# CSS background changing color - gradients

Tags: html, css

This is my code

```
-webkit-animation: AnimationName 30s ease infinite;
-moz-animation: AnimationName 30s ease infinite;
animation: AnimationName 30s ease infinite;

@-webkit-keyframes AnimationName {
    0%{background-position:0% 50%}
    50%{background-position:100% 50%}
    100%{background-position:0% 50%}
}
@-moz-keyframes AnimationName {
    0%{background-position:0% 50%}
    50%{background-position:100% 50%}
    100%{background-position:0% 50%}
}
@keyframes AnimationName { 
    0%{background-position:0% 50%}
    50%{background-position:100% 50%}
    100%{background-position:0% 50%}
}
```

So thats just basically a color changing background.
Whenever i run it on my html like this...

```
#navBar
{
font-family: "Century Gothic";
-webkit-animation: AnimationName 30s ease infinite;
-moz-animation: AnimationName 30s ease infinite;
animation: AnimationName 30s ease infinite;

@-webkit-keyframes AnimationName {
0%{background-position:0% 50%}
50%{background-position:100% 50%}
100%{background-position:0% 50%}
}
@-moz-keyframes AnimationName {
0%{background-position:0% 50%}
50%{background-position:100% 50%}
100%{background-position:0% 50%}
}
@keyframes AnimationName { 
0%{background-position:0% 50%}
50%{background-position:100% 50%}
100%{background-position:0% 50%}
}
}
```

I want it so that the background changes the color, but that doesnt happen. I think i have to add a background tag? Can someone make a codepen or something to make it work, i tried experimenting background tags and got nowhere.

Basically i want an animated navigation bar with the code (1st section).

Thank you very much.

If possible please only CSS and HTML! (Also make it simple too :D)

Comment: this moves the background?

Comment: Why are you expecting background-position to change the color?

Answer (score 1):

Your CSS is malformed, the keyframes goes outside of the selector like below. I'm unsure of what colors you want to change to but how keyframes works, you want to describe the state of the element at that moment... otherwise its just like css (also only syntax you need left is the -webkit-, unless you plan on supporting firefox back to v ~30 or so. So what the below says is: at 0 percent, move the background position 50% to the right at halfway through the animation you move down all the way and then at the last moment, move back to the original position it started off at

```
#navBar {
    font-family: "Century Gothic";
    -webkit-animation: AnimationName 30s ease infinite;
    -moz-animation: AnimationName 30s ease infinite;
    animation: AnimationName 30s ease infinite;
}

@-webkit-keyframes AnimationName {
   0%{background-position:0% 50%}
   50%{background-position:100% 50%}
   100%{background-position:0% 50%}
}
@-moz-keyframes AnimationName {
   0%{background-position:0% 50%}
   50%{background-position:100% 50%}
   100%{background-position:0% 50%}
}
@keyframes AnimationName { 
   0%{background-position:0% 50%}
   50%{background-position:100% 50%}
  100%{background-position:0% 50%}
}
```

with html

```
<div id="navBar"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

correct your syntax as @Deamedaor said

use **background-color** instead of background-position.

to try https://jsfiddle.net/vkbdtc47/

```
#navBar {
    font-family: "Century Gothic";
    -webkit-animation: AnimationName 30s ease infinite;
    -moz-animation: AnimationName 30s ease infinite;
    animation: AnimationName 30s ease infinite;
    background-color: #fff;
}
@-webkit-keyframes AnimationName {
   0%{background-color: #fff}
   50%{background-color:#f00}
   100%{background-color: #fff}
}
@-moz-keyframes AnimationName {
   0%{background-color: #fff}
   50%{background-color:#f00}
   100%{background-color: #fff}
}
@keyframes AnimationName { 
   0%{background-color: #fff}
   50%{background-color:#f00}
  100%{background-color: #fff}
}
```